# How can I configure android Tor browser version 9.5 to use my prefered exitnodes?

Tags: configuration, exit-relays

I have already attempted to

- **A:** Change `torrc` file located at `/data/data/org.torproject.torbrowser/app_torservice/torrc`, but this file is rewritten at app launch.
- **B:** Do the same but “live”, (i.e. browser running) hoping that when it changes nodes every so often as it does, it will use the new configuration specified.
- **C:** Tried editing the apk `torrc` file located in assets and installing modified apk. But none of these have worked. I read somewhere that what I want to do is “impossible” but I find that hard to believe, usually when I hear people say this it’s usually just cause they don't know how.

Also, I am putting the exit-relay tag since the question is specifically related to exits but there is no `exitnode` tag.

Comment: The Tor Browser for Android [does not](https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues/29031) currently allow you to modify the torrc. I suppose one method is to build the app yourself from source with the modifications you want.

Comment: @Steve - Honestly, I have no idea how to build something from source and don't have the ability if it requires anything more than a mobile device. I read the link you posted and had my intrest piqued by the comment "Tor Browser for Android (Alpha) no longer depends upon Orbot", can you explain this?

Comment: Earlier alpha versions of Tor Browser for Android used [Orbot](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orbot/) to connect to the Tor network, but it now uses the actual Tor client instead to connect to the network (like Tor Browser for Windows/Linux/Mac).

Comment: @Steve - I keep looking for information on the difference between using Orbot and Tor client but I can't find anything thats breaks it down. I'm interested because I use Tor browser to get past the censorship where I live but every attempt I've made to use Orbot has not worked. I contacted 5he guardian project but their only suggestion was to try to get a different set of bridges, something I already tried but did not work. Thanks for responding.

Comment: I don't use Android so I won't be much help here, so making a new question would be best so that other people can see it. But the Tor Browser (on both PC and Android) embed the Tor client directly into the browser package/app. Orbot is different in that it creates a system-wide proxy for Android phones, so you can use Tor for any app. Before Tor Browser for Android, there was [Orfox](https://guardianproject.info/apps/orfox), which was an Android browser that you could use with Orbot. If you only plan to do web browsing, the Tor Browser app is generally safer than using Orbot + another browser.

Comment: @Steve - Well thanks for your help anyway. I might make a new question specifically adressing the connection.